# dnsmasq - different subnet by wifi SSID - how?

Tags: wifi, dhcp, dnsmasq

I'm using dnsmasq on an ubuntu 14.04 server as my DHCP and DNS servers on my LAN. This device has only 1 ethernet NIC.

I want to setup a wireless Access Point with multiple SSID's. The wifi AP and dnsmasq are NOT the same device. I want to setup different subnets based on the wifi SSID the client device is connected to. How can I achieve this with dnsmasq?

dnsmasq would need to be able to identify the ssid the device is coming from in order to have different dhcp-range by ssid. Is this possible? How?

I've read lots on dnsmasq, but often the wifi and dnsmasq are the same device and it's never clear to me how dnsmasq can differentiate various SSID's.

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to have the AP tag the packets in some way. I don't think there's a standard out-of-the-box way for the client to report what SSID it is connecting with.

Comment: Anyone know how it's done in the corporate world? Wireless APs often have multiple SSIDs and DHCP servers are separate devices.

Answer (score 2):

normally this is done by diferent VLAN. Each SSID is mapped to one VLAN. In ethernet you should configure multiple VLAN access to your switch (that creates multiple virtual interfaces in your machine, each with one configuration: IP, mask, and so on in each network).

Search in google about how to configure VLAN in linux (example, first match from google: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html, or, second match: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_802_1Q_VLAN_Tagging_Using_the_Command_Line.html).

In your switch you need VLAN support (minimun some L2 switch with management)